# Truth of Goldbach conjecture and its relationship with provability from Peano axioms.

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

In lecture notes from Lou van den Dries, page 3 here - http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~vddries/main.pdf, it is said:

"However, in our present state of knowledge, $GC$ (Goldbach conjecture) might be true in $(\mathbb{N}; 0, 1, +, ·, <)$, but not provable from those axioms (Peano axioms). (On the other hand, once you know what exactly we mean by provable from the Peano axioms, you will see that if $GC$ is provable from those axioms, then $GC$ is true in $(\mathbb{N}; 0, 1, +, ·, <)$, and that if GC is false in $(\mathbb{N}; 0, 1, +, ·, <)$, then its negation $\neg GC$ is provable from those axioms.)"

Could someone please explain me why this is true? I don't know where to start. I'm sure if I go through the whole notes I might get a better idea of why this is true, but given my understanding that's quite far away from where I am now, and this is a nice concrete example of something interesting, that I'd like to understand now. A pointer to where exactly in the notes I should look would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key fact is:

> Every model of $PA$ is an end extension of $\mathbb{N}$.

This means that any statement using only bounded quantifiers which is true in $\mathbb{N}$ is true in every model of $PA$.

The other key fact is:

> Every element of $\mathbb{N}$ is definable in every model of $PA$, by a bounded formula.

For instance, $0$ is defined as the unique $x$ such that "$\forall y<x(y\not=y)$". *Note that this does **not** mean that the **set** $\mathbb{N}$ is definable in $M$, for every $M\models PA$; in fact, it **never** is.*

Now suppose Goldbach is false. Then there is some even $n>2$ such that $n$ cannot be written as the sum of two primes. But this is a bounded statement in terms of $n$: clearly those primes must be $<n$, so the quantifier over primes is bounded; and saying that an element is prime involves quantifying over only numbers less than it. Finally, since $n$ itself is definable by a bounded formula, there is a single sentence $\varphi$, using only bounded quantifiers, which expresses "$n$ is a counterexample to Goldbach". This sentence is true in every model of $PA$, since every model of $PA$ is an end extension of $\mathbb{N}$; so by the Completeness Theorem, $PA\vdash\varphi$. But then $PA$ disproves Goldbach.

---

Note that this hinges on the fact that Goldbach being false would be witnessed by a single bounded statement about a single natural number (some counterexample). Goldbach being *true*, however, would not be. So if Goldbach is true, $PA$ might still not be able to prove it.

A statement like the Twin Prime Conjecture is even worse. What is a counterexample to TPC? Well, it's an $n$ such that there is no twin prime above $n$. So the failure of TPC would be witnessed by a single natural number. But the statement that $n$ is a counterexample to TPC involves an unbounded quantifier - " . . . above $n$"! So even if TPC is false, $PA$ might not know. And TPC being true isn't witnessed by a *single* example, but rather *infinitely many* - so even though being a twin prime is a bounded statement, TPC being true need not imply that $PA$ proves TPC.

This kind of distinction between mathematical principles leads to a [natural hierarchy of sentences of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy) - the **arithmetic hierarchy** - which is intensively studied (along with its extensions and generalizations) throughout mathematical logic:

- In [computability theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computability_theory), unbounded quantifiers roughly correspond to the [Turing jump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_jump), a generalization of the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem). This operation is fundamental in computability theory; there is a natural extension of the arithmetic hierarchy to transfinite iterates of the Turing jump, called the [hyperarithmetic hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperarithmetical_theory), which in turn is connected with quantifiers in [infinitary logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitary_logic).
- In [model theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_theory), the structure of quantifiers in a sentence can determine the kinds of algebraic operations on its models which preserve its truth; see e.g. [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%81o%C5%9B%E2%80%93Tarski_preservation_theorem). This is essentially the arithmetic hierarchy generalized to arbitrary structures.
- In [set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory), the [Levy hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_hierarchy) is the generalization of the arithmetic hierarchy; quantifiers of the form "$\forall x\in a$" take the place of quantifiers of the form "$\forall n<k$". Additionally, a [second-order analogue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_hierarchy) of the arithmetical hierarchy plays a fundamental role in [descriptive set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descriptive_set_theory), and in the [analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absoluteness#Shoenfield.27s_absoluteness_theorem) of [forcing extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forcing_(mathematics)).
- In [proof theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_theory), [theories of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms) are fruitfully studied by stratifying them into hierarchies of weaker theories via the arithmetic hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. 

How would the proof of the other claim go (If $GC$ is provable from PA, then it is true in $\mathbb{N}$) ? I can see that if $PA$ is presumed to be consistent, then we can just presume $GC$ to be false, to get a contradiction using the claim you've already explained.

What if $PA$ is inconsistent?

Comment: @JohnP PA is "known" to be consistent: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gentzen's_consistency_proof

Comment: Ah alright. Would it be possible to show that if $GC$ is probable from $PA$, then it is true in $\mathbb{N}$, without using consistency of $PA$ ?

Comment: @JohnP No - if $PA$ is inconsistent then it proves *everything* (including GC).

Comment: @NoahSchweber Oh, of course, I forgot. So it doesn't 'imply' $GC$ is true in $\mathbb{N}$, because the fact that $GC$ is provable doesn't really give us any information (since $PA$ is inconsistent), and thus at that point, that implication would in some sense be equivalent to an actual proof/argument of $GC$ being true in $\mathbb{N}$, do I understand that right?

Comment: @JohnP I think so, yes (although the meaning of "at that point, that implication would in some sense be equivalent to an actual proof/argument of GC being true in ℕ" isn't clear to me)

Comment: @NoahSchweber What I meant is that if I have some sort of statement $A \Rightarrow B$, where $A$ doesn't really have anything to do with $B$, but we do know $A$ is true, then $A \Rightarrow B$ is true iff $B$ is true.

"($1=1$) implies (there exists a number larger than $0$)" is true, but we might aswell just say the second statement is true by itself.

In this sense, presuming $PA$ is inconsistent, "($GC$ is provable from $PA$) implies ($GC$ is true in $\mathbb{N}$)"  might be true, but we might aswell just say that "$GC$ is true in $\mathbb{N}$".

Comment: @JohnP I see. Then yes, that's correct.